# Unable to create google cloud storage bucket in a zone [terraform]

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, terraform

I am trying to create a gcs bucket using terraform in the region `us-west1-a` with the `storage-class` as `REGIONAL`. But I am getting this error when doing so

```
* google_storage_bucket.terraform-state: 1 error(s) occurred:

* google_storage_bucket.terraform-state: googleapi: Error 400: The combination of locationConstraint and storageClass you provided is not supported for your project, invalid
```

Here is the `.tf` file I have right now

```
resource "google_storage_bucket" "terraform-state" {
  name          = "terraform-state"
  storage_class = "${var.storage-class}"
}

provider "google" {
  credentials = "${file("${path.module}/../credentials/account.json")}"
  project     = "${var.project-name}"
  region      = "${var.region}"
}

variable "region" {
  default = "us-west1" # Oregon
}

variable "project-name" {
  default = "my-project"
}

variable "location" {
  default = "US"
}

variable "storage-class" {
  default = "REGIONAL"
}
```

Docs

- https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/storage_bucket.html
- https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-locations

Answer (score 5):

The location specified in the CreateBucket request is a region, not a zone (see definitions at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/regions-zones). "us-west1-a" is a zone. Please try the request with "us-west1" (which is the region that contains the us-west1-a zone) instead.

Comment: I had the same issue with a different error message (a few years later): 
  
`google_storage_bucket.tf-bucket: Creating...  
Error: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid Value, invalid`. 
  
I wish this were a bit more descriptive...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't actually specified a location in the resource, so it is defaulting to "us" which is invalid as that is not a region. Try:

```
resource "google_storage_bucket" "terraform-state" {
  name          = "terraform-state"
  storage_class = "${var.storage-class}"
  location      = "${var.location}"
}

variable "location" {
  default = "us-west1"
}

variable "storage-class" {
  default = "REGIONAL"
}
```

Notice that I have added "location" to the resource and set the location variable to the actual GCS location desired.